# Android - Double lifecycle sequence from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm monitoring an `Activity` lifecycle to learn more on it, so I put a `Log.d()` call in almost every method of the cycle.

I'm watching particularly the sequence:

```
[A]onSaveInstanceState() - onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy() - onStart() - [B]onRestoreInstanceState()
```

See [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Switching a 2.2 Froyo emulator with Ctrl-F11 from **portrait to landscape** I can see **one** round from [A] to [B].

What is strange to me is that switching back **from landscape to portrait** I can see **two** round from [A] to [B].

```
onSaveInstanceState() - onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy() - onStart() - onRestoreInstanceState()
onSaveInstanceState() - onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy() - onStart() - onRestoreInstanceState()
```

This is creating me lots of issues in saving/restoring the activity state.

How can it be? Why is it so?

**Edited:** Using a 2.3.3 Gingerbread emulator the sequence runs only once. But 2.3.3 emulator has a known bug that prevents it from rotating correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Rotation in emulator is different from Accelerator rotation. It actually simulates an open-keyboard.
These are two different events, which cause two different lify-cycle flows.

Comment: According to [Using the Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) there exist only Ctrl-F11/F12 to "Swith to previous/next layout orientation". Is not an Accelerator rotation key? How can be it emulated? What are this "different lifecycle" flows?

Answer (score 0):

Its happen some times on emulators, check it on real device, it works properly on real devices.