# Problem when switching layouts from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have two layouts one for portrait one for landscape. For portrait I have it under the layout folder and for landscape I have it under the layout-land folder. Both have the same name main.xml. The switching happens without any errors fro portrait to landscape. Again when I switch from landscape to portrait, for some reason its not loading the portrait based layout and is unable to find the root layout I have defined. Here's the Logcat output\

```
07-27 15:25:09.601: WARN/System.err(278): java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.LinearLayout
07-27 15:25:10.230: WARN/System.err(278):     at  com.me2youmob.swagwrap.ChickenWrapActivity.loadMBIIntoView(ChickenWrapActivity.java:102)
07-27 15:25:10.230: WARN/System.err(278):     at com.me2youmob.swagwrap.ChickenWrapActivity.onCreate(ChickenWrapActivity.java:41)
07-27 15:25:10.230: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-27 15:25:10.250: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-27 15:25:10.250: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-27 15:25:10.250: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
07-27 15:25:10.311: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-27 15:25:10.311: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
07-27 15:25:10.311: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 15:25:10.322: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 15:25:10.322: WARN/System.err(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-27 15:25:10.329: WARN/System.err(278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 15:25:10.329: WARN/System.err(278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 15:25:10.361: WARN/System.err(278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-27 15:25:10.361: WARN/System.err(278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-27 15:25:10.371: WARN/System.err(278):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code that's there in onCreate is as follows

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    int deviceRotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Utils.spPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Utils.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (deviceRotation == 1)
    {
        int imgID = Utils.getMbiIndex("mbiIndex");  
        int drawBgId = Utils.getMbiDrawIndex(imgID);
        try 
        {
            ImageView ivLandView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLandMbi);
            ivLandView.setImageResource(drawBgId);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                   
    }
    else
    {
        loadMBIIntoView();
        handleButtonClicks(); 
    }
}
```

The error happenson the loadMBIIntoView method where the code is as follows

```
    public void loadMBIIntoView() 
{
    int imgID = Utils.getMbiIndex("mbiIndex");  
    int drawBgId = Utils.getMbiDrawIndex(imgID);
    try {
        RelativeLayout llMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawMbi = res.getDrawable(drawBgId);
        llMain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawMbi);          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The landscape layout does not have rlMain layout itself but the portrait does. If the activity is being restarted(which is fine with me) everytime I change the screen mode shouldn't it automatically load the appropriate layouts ? I would appreciate any help on this. Thank You.

UPDATE : 02:00 PM

I added the code but its still give the same error. The error crops up because of the casting of a linear layout into a relative layout and this is where the issue is. The portrait layout("main.xml") is in its default "layout" folder. This layout has the relative layout("rlmain"). The landscape layout("main.xml") resides in the layout-land folder. This main.xml has different UI specifications and has the linear layout. By default I load in portrait mode where it loads fine and the I press Ctrl + F11 to change it to Landscape, the layout from layout-land folder loads fine. Then I press Ctrl + F11 again to change to Portrait where the main.xml from the default layout folder should have loaded but is not getting loaded which is why I am getting the case exception.

Comment: The landscape file doesn't contain rlMain?  Android will automatically switch between the layouts in layout and layout-land, but it won't create layouts that aren't there.  If rlMain isn't in the landscape file, findViewById(R.id.rlMain) will return null and you will get errors when you try to use it.

Comment: Yes the landscape file does not contain rlMain. I have put the constraint in place so that when the landscape mode is activated rlMain is not called. The error comes up when I switch back to the portrait mode when it should load the portrait layout and should be able to find the rlMain.

Comment: Got it.  Well what's on line 102 of ChickenWrapActivity?

Comment: Do you have a default layout for both landscape and portrait in the layout folder, and not just layout-portrait and layout-landscape?  It would also help if you could include the stacktrace that gives the exact line where the error is occurring.

Comment: @theisenp, line 102 is trying to get the rlMain instance RelativeLayout llMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);

Comment: @Pheonixbalde9 Layout for portrait mode is in default layout folder and for landscape I have kept it in layout-land folder. I have included the stack trace in the first post. The exact line is where it is trying to get an instance of rlMain as specified in the above comment.

Comment: @Phoenixblade9 The stack trace is there, and the error is at 102.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to cast a LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout, but that doesn't make much sense since it originally works in portrait mode.  It might be a problem with your if statement in onCreate() though.  It's possible that your loadMBIIntoView() function is called when it shouldn't be, causing the error.

You test for deviceRotation == 1, but that only catches the case where the device is rotated 90 degrees, ignoring the case where it is rotated 270 degrees.

Try this instead and see if anything changes:

```
if(deviceRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || deviceRotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Surface.ROTATION_90 is a pre-defined constant that equals 1, and Surface.ROTATION_270 equals 3.

**EDIT:**

I still think it's a problem with your deviceRotation.  Ctrl + F11 goes to the "previous layout orientation" while Ctrl + F12 goes to the "next layout orientation" as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).  So when you press F11 twice you are not returning to the original orientation.  You are switching to an upside down portrait mode.

Try pressing F11 the first time, and then F12 the second time, so that the emulator really does return to it's true original state and see if that still causes an error.

**EDIT #2:**

This appears to be a problem [(possibly a bug)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2423) with emulator rotation.
A similar question to this one can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481793/screen-orientation-landscape-back-to-portrait-not-working).

Essentially, the emulator makes extra lifecycle calls that a real device doesn't.  Supposedly it simulates rotation by [opening the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484108/android-double-lifecycle-sequence-from-landscape-to-portrait) instead of through the accelerometer as a real device would.

If you can, I would test your code on a real device to see if it's a legitimate issue.  Right now it seems like it's just a problem with the emulator and you should ignore it.

Comment: I was unable to type the whole thing so I have added an update to my original post. Your thoughts are correct about layout casting, problem is the wrong layout is getting loaded in portrait mode and I am not sure why its happening that way.

Comment: That worked :) Thanks a ton. If I press Ctrl + F12 it's working But does that mean that on phone when the device is turned upside down, the layout will crash ?

Comment: Yes, it will still crash when you turn it upside down.  But now we know that the error is specifically related to rotation.  Have you updated the if statement as I suggested?

Comment: Yes I did update the statement, it was crashing if I press Ctrl + F11 thrice but not when pressing Ctrl + F11 followed by Ctrl + F12 and then again by Ctrl + F11.

Comment: Thank You @theisenp, I will test it on the device also. Thank You again for your time on this, Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. It got it resolved.   The main problem with it is when you switch from landscape to portrait, the activity is not refreshing. You can do one thing, override the onConfigurationChanged and implement like this. It will refresh the activity.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    startActivity(getIntent());
    finish();

}
```

It will help you.  Please reply if your problem get solved.

Comment: If your intention is really to refresh/recreate activity then why even bother dealing with onConfigurationChanged() at all ? just take out android:configChanges from activity in manifest and it would automatically recreate your activity anyway. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Add these line AndroidManifest.xml to your activity which you want to give orientation.

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

In Code use these lines for orientation change

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Also keep in mind to set orientation after <"setContentView"> as

setContentView(R.layout.main);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);